# Firebase Data Model For an iOS Poker Game

Tags: json, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, database-design, nosql

I'm working on a hobby project for myself and I'm using Firebase for my auth, storage, and db. I love the tools and it makes a lot of sense to me. But I'm curious about how I should structure my data model to work with my UI. I think I know, but I'd love some feedback.

I currently have collections for Users and Tables (poker table in this case). The UI will have a recent tables page where I'll list all the tables the user has played on, using a query based on their UID. Each Table will consist of some top level info (table name, game type, date started, etc). The user can then see details of a table (people who they played with, number hands played, total winnings, etc). They can also go into each Hand and see the history as a list of Actions per user for each Round.

I first tried to add players as an array of objects to each table, but quickly realized that's not a great way to query. So instead I'm adding a sub-collection of Players, as well as a sub-collection of Hands. The Players collection will have documents with info on each player (using their UID as the document name) and that's about it.

Hands will have a bit more info, and more sub-collections, as it's made up of Rounds, which in turn is made up of Actions.

Is this an ok route to take? Can I eventually query across all this info? Should I consider keeping Rounds as an array of objects and parse it out on the client side? Should I also consider having a Hand collection at the root instead? and only store an array of "handIDs" in the Table document?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!!

Here's my rough data model:

[Table Collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QvOMr.png)

[Players and Hands Collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIT3N.png)

[Round Collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yEFWT.png)

[Action Collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZLXI.png)

Here's some model designs I've been working on:

```
Table Model
{
   "id":"bQyEVWpft2muwsjDG0P8",
   "tableCode":"THXHR",
   "hostID" : "JoGcB09L7gfRCNzY9QTr6vb7IsS2"
   "tableIsActive":false,
   "tableName":"Mikes's Poker Table",
   "buyInAmount" : 20, 
   "tableSize":9,
   "gameType":"NLH",
   "gameFormat":"Tournament",
   "minChipValue":5,
   "startTime":"2021-05-21T06:00:30",
   "endTime":"2021-05-21T08:00:30",
   "playerIDs":[
        "JfF3in8kc3efboE5ug9iwYWFInm2",
        "oMK9dGaFATNyR1zqtA3Hm981UvJ2",
        "fN8wCkhzxxMnreNweH4niEHUtsm2",
        "JoGcB09L7gfRCNzY9QTr6vb7IsS2"
   ],
   "handIDs" : [
        "dfa247d0-1526-4080-b3dc-d3636d924582",
        "5508c238-0bad-47fd-a04f-3bceed7f82ca",
        "6581554e-3f1c-490e-b374-e1bfd4e74cfd",
        "4d4b6b79-bddb-4492-b88c-d2fe3205c478",
        "92741343-997e-46cc-99f6-dc155389732d",
        "b643ddd0-178a-4414-88bd-87b3671b02c5"
   ]
}
```

```
Hand Model
{
   "id":"dfa247d0-1526-4080-b3dc-d3636d924582",
   "tableID":"bQyEVWpft2muwsjDG0P8",
   "flags":[],
   "startTime":"2021-05-21T07:53:30",
   "endTime":"2021-05-21T07:55:30",
   "currency":"USD",
   "anteAmount":0.00,
   "smallBlindAmount":5,
   "bigBlindAmount":10,
   "straddleOn":false,
   "dealerSeat":1,
   "players":[  
      {
         "name":"Scott",
         "playerID":"JfF3in8kc3efboE5ug9iwYWFInm2",
         "startingStack":1500,
         "seat":1,
         "cards":[ "Qs","As"]
      },
      {
         "name":"Michelle",
         "playerID":"oMK9dGaFATNyR1zqtA3Hm981UvJ2",
         "startingStack":1500,
         "seat":2,
         "cards":[ "2s","3s"]
      },
      {
         "name":"Noah",
         "playerID":"fN8wCkhzxxMnreNweH4niEHUtsm2",
         "startingStack":1500,
         "seat":3,
         "cards":[ "4s","5s"]
      },
      {
         "name":"Dave",
         "playerID":"JoGcB09L7gfRCNzY9QTr6vb7IsS2",
         "startingStack":1500,
         "seat":4,
         "cards":["6s","7s"]
      }
   ],
   "rounds":[
      {
         "id":0,
         "publicCards":[],
         "street":"Preflop",
         "actions":[
            {
               "actionID":1,
               "playerID":"oMK9dGaFATNyR1zqtA3Hm981UvJ2",
               "action":"Post SB",
               "amount":5,
               "isAllIn":false
            },
            {
               "actionID":2,
               "playerID":"fN8wCkhzxxMnreNweH4niEHUtsm2",
               "action":"Post BB",
               "amount":10,
               "isAllIn":false
            },
            {
               "actionID":3,
               "playerID":"JoGcB09L7gfRCNzY9QTr6vb7IsS2",
               "action":"Call",
               "amount":10,
               "isAllIn":false
            },
            {
               "actionID":4,
               "playerID":"JfF3in8kc3efboE5ug9iwYWFInm2",
               "action":"Call",
               "amount":10,
               "isAllIn":false
            },
            {
               "actionID":5,
               "playerID":"oMK9dGaFATNyR1zqtA3Hm981UvJ2",
               "action":"Call",
               "amount":5,
               "isAllIn":false
            },
            {
               "actionID":6,
               "playerID":"fN8wCkhzxxMnreNweH4niEHUtsm2",
               "action":"Check",
               "amount":0,
               "isAllIn":false
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "id":1,
         "publicCards":[ "2d","Kc","Qc"],
         "street":"Flop",
         "actions":[
             {
               "actionID":1,
               "playerID":"oMK9dGaFATNyR1zqtA3Hm981UvJ2",
               "action":"Check",
               "amount":0,
               "isAllIn":false
            },
            {
               "actionID":2,
               "playerID":"fN8wCkhzxxMnreNweH4niEHUtsm2",
               "action":"Bet",
               "amount":10,
               "isAllIn":false
            },
            {
               "actionID":3,
               "playerID":"JoGcB09L7gfRCNzY9QTr6vb7IsS2",
               "action":"Call",
               "amount":10,
               "isAllIn":false
            },
            {
               "actionID":4,
               "playerID":"JfF3in8kc3efboE5ug9iwYWFInm2",
               "action":"Call",
               "amount":10,
               "isAllIn":false
            },
            {
               "actionID":5,
               "playerID":"oMK9dGaFATNyR1zqtA3Hm981UvJ2",
               "action":"Call",
               "amount":10,
               "isAllIn":false
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "id":2,
         "publicCards":["2d","Kc","Qc","7d"],
         "street":"Turn",
         "actions":[
             {
               "actionID":1,
               "playerID":"oMK9dGaFATNyR1zqtA3Hm981UvJ2",
               "action":"Check",
               "amount":0,
               "isAllIn":false
            },
            {
               "actionID":2,
               "playerID":"fN8wCkhzxxMnreNweH4niEHUtsm2",
               "action":"Check",
               "amount":0,
               "isAllIn":false
            },
            {
               "actionID":3,
               "playerID":"JoGcB09L7gfRCNzY9QTr6vb7IsS2",
               "action":"Check",
               "amount":0,
               "isAllIn":false
            },
            {
               "actionID":4,
               "playerID":"JfF3in8kc3efboE5ug9iwYWFInm2",
               "action":"Check",
               "amount":0,
               "isAllIn":false
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "id":3,
         "publicCards":["2d","Kc","Qc","7d","3d"],
         "street":"River",
         "actions":[
            {
               "actionID":1,
               "playerID":"oMK9dGaFATNyR1zqtA3Hm981UvJ2",
               "action":"Bet",
               "amount":20,
               "isAllIn":false
            },
            {
               "actionID":2,
               "playerID":"fN8wCkhzxxMnreNweH4niEHUtsm2",
               "action":"Fold",
               "amount":0,
               "isAllIn":false
            },
            {
               "actionID":3,
               "playerID":"JoGcB09L7gfRCNzY9QTr6vb7IsS2",
               "action":"Raise",
               "amount":40,
               "isAllIn":false
            },
            {
               "actionID":4,
               "playerID":"JfF3in8kc3efboE5ug9iwYWFInm2",
               "action":"Call",
               "amount":40,
               "isAllIn":false
            },
            {
               "actionID":5,
               "playerID":"oMK9dGaFATNyR1zqtA3Hm981UvJ2",
               "action":"Call",
               "amount":20,
               "isAllIn":false
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "id":4,
         "publicCards":["2d","Kc","Qc","7d","3d"],
         "street":"Showdown",
         "actions":[
            {
               "actionID":1,
               "playerID":"oMK9dGaFATNyR1zqtA3Hm981UvJ2",
               "action":"Show Cards",
               "amount":0,
               "isAllIn":false
            },
            {
               "actionID":2,
               "playerID":"JoGcB09L7gfRCNzY9QTr6vb7IsS2",
               "action":"Show Cards",
               "amount":0,
               "isAllIn":false
            },
            {
               "actionID":3,
               "playerID":"JfF3in8kc3efboE5ug9iwYWFInm2",
               "action":"Payout",
               "amount":200,
               "isAllIn":false
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "pots":[
      {
        "number":0,
        "amount":200,
        "winningPlayers":[
            {
                "playerID":"JfF3in8kc3efboE5ug9iwYWFInm2",
                "winAmount":200,
                "winningHandName":"Two-Pair"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "summary" : {
        "totalPot" : 200,
        "publicCards" : ["2d","Kc","Qc","7d","3d"],
        "winners" : [
            JfF3in8kc3efboE5ug9iwYWFInm2
        ],
        "losers" : [
            "JoGcB09L7gfRCNzY9QTr6vb7IsS2",
            "oMK9dGaFATNyR1zqtA3Hm981UvJ2"
        ],
        "folded" : [
            "fN8wCkhzxxMnreNweH4niEHUtsm2"
        ]
   }
}
```

Comment: We are usually structuring a Firestore database according to the queries that we want to perform. What are those queries?

Comment: @AlexMamo The big query would be to get all Tables that the user has played at, using their UID. My UI is mainly driven by Table history, and I can dig down into each Hand that makes up an entire Table history. (Table -> Hand -> Round > Action) I would also be writing to Tables in progress by updating the current Hand. I'd have other stats (win%, fold%, best hand, P&L, etc) that would theoretically be calculated client side.